# Differential Equation- show y satisfies the diff eqn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $p \in \mathbb{R}$. Find the radius of convergence of the series

$$y(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {p \choose n} x^n$$

I found the ROC to be 1!

Now I need to show that,

Show $y$ satisfies the differential equation $(1 + x )y' = py$ and solve it to find $y(x)$ in closed form.

Comment: Is this right?  You have factorials of negative numbers in the denominator there.

Comment: If $n=p+1$, then you will have ${p\choose p+1}$, which can't be right. Perhaps *restrict* the upper limit to $p$?